# IOS BLE notifications are not getting caught, didUpdateValueFor not working

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have implemented **connection** from IOS device to the **peripheral** device.
Then i have also implemented **fetching** available **services** and **characteristics** of these services.
It's been also made possible to call

```
peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic) or
peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
```

Calling `peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)` triggers 
`func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) { }` and it gets value from a **cache**. It looks like there is no way to **refresh/clear** **cache** programmatically in IOS. So every time it gets called it gets back the **same value** until the **cache** is not cleaned up manually by relaunching the app/BLE.

After calling `peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)` it successfully updates the state of peripheral and also calls the same delegate method

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) { } just once.
```

Have been trying to accomplish the task with IOS 11 and 12, iphone X, 6+, 6s Plus. The device **works fine with Android**, it can get **value update notifications** with. The device has been also checked with RxBluetoothKit example app, the result was the same as mine(couldn't get notifications).

Seems like a lot of people are having the same trouble. It could be a bug in Core Bluetooth or IOS versions so it limits the range of Hz, which is used for notifications.

Could, you, please share any other ideas or possible solutions of how to fix that so it would be possible to get notifications from the peripheral. The option of clearing the cache programmatically would also help (some people have mentioned some tricky hacks for that).

Update: device works with OSX and MacBook Pro 2014 and BlueSee app, but doesn't work with the same BlueSee app for IOS and iPhone 6s Plus.

Comment: First, try connecting to your peripheral using the LightBlue app and see if it receives updated data; There is either a problem with your peripheral or a problem with your iOS code.  There is no "cache".

Comment: I was trying both approaches with setNotifyValue and readValue either. Separately as well. I tried notifications first then since it wasn't possible to use (didUpdateValueFor is not working) them I tried just to send the request using the timer.

Comment: I have already tried LightBlue and it wasn't possible to get data updated. But it works with a similar Android app. Just in case if there was a problem with my code I tried the same thing using RxBluetoothKit example app, the result was the same.

Comment: Then the problem is with your peripheral.

Comment: @Paulw11 but it works with Android.

Comment: Well, it could be a bug with iOS but there are millions of iOS devices communicating with millions of BLE devices...

Comment: Definitely, there are. There are also quite a lot of people (not as much, of course) writing about the similar issues arisen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187478/discussion-between-paulw11-and-alexander).

Comment: @Alexander, I am also trying to achieve the same with the android device, but I am not able to get notifications characteristics. Could you please help me with or guide me on how can I achieve this as you were able to fetch the characteristics. Thank you in advance.